# GCP API Gateway authentication between services without using service account private key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-api-gateway

How can I setup an API Gateway to authenticate services without using service account private key file?

Service A, for instance a cloud function, with service account A wants to make API calls to an API gateway without using service account private key file. I am wondering if it is possible that service A uses its credentials to make an API call where the API Gateway can authenticate the request?

Being able to do the above, the API gateway can be configured to allow various paths to different service accounts.

**Updated**

This is an example of what a client code could be

```
def make_jwt_request(signed_jwt, url):
    """Makes an authorized request to the endpoint"""
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(signed_jwt),
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Also, the API Gateway definition would be something like

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: API_ID optional-string
  description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  google:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "service-b@example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-b@example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
paths:
  /helloworld:
    get:
      summary: Hello World
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-example-project.cloudfunctions.net/function-b
      security:
        - google: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Comment: Just for clarification. You want to call an API Gateway which check the authorisation header (with a token generated by a service account key file) BUT you don't want to have a service account key file in the service A, because it's a secret and you have difficulties to handle it safely. correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere exactly. GCP allows something similar to what I am looking for in a cloud function to function call, https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use the credential of the function A. Can you share the piece of code where you perform the call to API Gateway ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I updated the initial post to include a sample code

Comment: How are you creating the Signed JWT? If you are trying to ask, How do I sign the JWT without a JSON private key, then you can use IAM SignBlob API. When you are using credentials from a service's metadata, the private key is not available. Google offers an API to sign data for you. At the bottom of this link are examples in most languages: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks John, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You are able to sign jwt's without a private key using the [sign_jwt](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt) iamcredentials endpoint.

Now assuming the following security definition you can use the following python code to generate a signed jwt.

```
   {
        "securityDefinitions": {
            "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME": {
                "authorizationUrl": "",
                "flow": "implicit",
                "type": "oauth2",
                "x-google-audiences": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL",
                "x-google-issuer": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL",
                "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"
            }
        }
    }
```

python script

```
import time
import json 
import urllib.parse
import requests
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

def generate_jwt_payload(service_account_email):
    """Generates jwt payload"""
    now = int(time.time())
    payload = {
        'iat': now,
        "exp": now + 3600,
        'iss': service_account_email,
        'aud':  service_account_email,
        'sub': service_account_email,
        'email': service_account_email
    }
    return payload

def get_jwt(service_account_email):
    """Generate a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account."""

    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = discovery.build('iamcredentials', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    body = {
        "payload": json.dumps(generate_jwt_payload(service_account_email))
    }
    encoded_sa = urllib.parse.quote_plus(service_account_email)
    resp = service.projects().serviceAccounts().signJwt(name=f"projects/-/serviceAccounts/{encoded_sa}", body=body).execute()
    return resp["signedJwt"]


def make_jwt_request(service_account_email, url):
    """Makes an authorized request to the endpoint"""
    signed_jwt = get_jwt(service_account_email)
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(signed_jwt),
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(make_jwt_request(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,GATEWAY_URL).text)
```